# Will there be memory leak in unique_ptr here

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   unique_ptr<int> p(new int);
   *p = 10;
   cout<<*p<<endl;
   p = NULL;
   if(p)
     cout<<"It's NOT NULL\n";
   else
     cout<<"It's NULL NOW\n";
   return 0;
}
```

// As I assigned NULL to p , when the program finishes , it will delete p which //has NULL . Though deleting NULL won't cause any issue but the memory hold by p //earlier won't get freed . Am I correct .

Comment: When you ask question, enter tag for the language you used for code. You question w/o c++ tag, will not be seen by c++ developers to answer you question.

Comment: Just FYI, coding that up to use something you *can* witness destruction of therein rather than simply `int`, such as a simple class-type where you dump to stdout in the destructor, would probably have nudged you down the right road.

Answer (score 6):

There will be no memory leak, although you should use `p = nullptr` rather than `p = NULL`. This is because `std::unique_ptr` overloads the assignment operator for the `nullptr_t` type:

From the standard, the effect of

`unique_ptr& operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept;`

is to call `reset()`. And that, in turn, frees any pointed-to memory.